# Lucene .tim file size reduce

Tags: lucene

I have lucene index (not very small, about 20gb) and I noticed that .tim file is about 16GB. I know that this is terms dictionary, is there any way to somehow to to reduce its size or even to entirely get rid off and if yes, what will I lose if I'll do this.

Thanks